# Test en django no funciona

Tags: django, test

Hay algo que necesite para poder realizar tests en django? MI codigo es este:

```
from django.test import TestCase

# Create your tests here.
class Test(TestCase):
    def function(self):
        print('Hola')
```

Pero cuando lo quiero correr

```
python manage.py test
```

Me sale que se corrierion 0 test. Como puedo hacer para realizar tests???

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/), los tests se construyen así:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.models import Animal

class AnimalTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        Animal.objects.create(name="lion", sound="roar")
        Animal.objects.create(name="cat", sound="meow")

    def test_animals_can_speak(self):
        """Animals that can speak are correctly identified"""
        lion = Animal.objects.get(name="lion")
        cat = Animal.objects.get(name="cat")
        self.assertEqual(lion.speak(), 'The lion says "roar"')
        self.assertEqual(cat.speak(), 'The cat says "meow"')
```

Es decir, cada función dentro de la clase corre un escenario y la instancia de la clase recibe como parámetro a TestCase

Cuando se corren los tests, el comportamiento estándar es que busca todos los test cases (subclases de unittest.TestCase) en cualquier archivo *cuyo nombre comience con **test***

Para ejecutarlos, bien puedes usar

```
$ ./manage.py test
```